# MAS (Mac App Store) Black background at Apps Icons

Tags: macos, icons, app-store

Has anyone got any solution for the recently Mac App Store problem regarding the black ugly background of any new or update app. I mention that this happen since 29-Jul.

Comment: The same thing happened to me today, please let me know if you find any workaround or solution...

Comment: A thread was opened at: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/238543.... According to Apple Support: "Thank you for contacting App Store Developer Support.
 
We are aware of the issue you are reporting regarding the app icons on the Mac App Store and are diligently working to resolve it.
 
I hope that this information is useful to you. Please let me know if you require any further assistance."

Comment: They replied to me a similar message, then it's fixed now. I think anyone who encounters the issue should report the issue, and they do their best.